# Draw Hyperlink Using String builder In C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, stringbuilder

I want to Draw a hyper Link in C# using stringbuilder when i create a hyper link this way :

```
StringBuilder HTMLCurrBuilder = new StringBuilder();
HyperLink lnk = new HyperLink();
lnk.Text = GetGlobalResourceObject("Registration", "download").ToString();
lnk.NavigateUrl = DataVal;

HTMLCurrBuilder.Append(lnk );
```

it make nothing is there is any way to do that in c#

Comment: What do you mean by "it make nothing"? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and clarify your question.

Comment: System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink

Comment: Okay, so that's the result of calling `ToString()` on a `HyperLink`. Why are you trying to use a web control with a StringBuilder like this? That's not how they're designed to be used.

Comment: What is `GetGlobalResourceObject()`? When you call `ToString()` on an object, it usually returns the class' qualified name, because most objects cannot be sensibly represented as strings. Only classes which override ToString() return a sensible string value. What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: i am using web control beacuse i want have a nother application which i want to draw this hyber link in so i sent it the array of links

Comment: get global resource is for geting the description of this file from resource file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use a PlaceHolder, and add this links in the PlaceHolder controls

```
 cPlaceHolderID.Controls.Append(lnk );
```

Then you place the PlaceHolder somewhere in your page and you get the rendered structure.

The StringBuilder is to build strings only, not html structures.

### Alternative one

You can simple build the link

```
HTMLCurrBuilder.AppendFormat("<a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>",DataVal,
   GetGlobalResourceObject("Registration", "download"));
```

this is very fast way and you get the same results in stringBuilder as you won. Actually and the HyperLink do something similar.

### Alternative two

you can render the control, and add the result to strinbuilder, but its toooo much.

Comment: the problm is i am drawing this section in run time so if i tried to appent this control i will not find it

Comment: @EslamSoliman All this solutions are to make it at run time. What you do not understand of the first two ? (leave aside the alternative two)

Comment: thanks i got confiused by the place holder control but it up and working now